# Array as parameter in ruby

Tags: ruby

Iam trying to get list of everything that failed.ie catch error message if any one of the `id` is not found.Follwoing is a capybara automation script.

In the following code exception handling is working fine!

```
  puts "Verifying Home Page"
      def verifyHomepage(id, successMsg, errorMsg)
       begin   
        page.find(id)
        puts successMsg
       rescue
        puts errorMsg
       end
    end

   verifyHomepage("#logoAnchor", "logo anchor found", "Logo anchor not Found")
   verifyHomepage(".navbar-inner", "Header Bar found", "Header Bar  not Found")
   verifyHomepage(".unstyled", "All Occasions Frame found", "All Occasions Frame not Found")
   verifyHomepage("##easyPrintPromoBox", "Easy Print Frame", "Easy Print Frame not Found")
   verifyHomepage(".tabbable", "l3 Tabs  Featured Occasions/Pairings/ArtistEasy Print Frame", "3 Tabs  Featured Occasions/Pairings/ArtistEasy Print Frame Not found")
   verifyHomepage("##givingCardPromoBox", "Create the perfect gift found", "Create the perfect gift not Found")
   verifyHomepage(".footerr", "Footer Frame found", "Footer Frame found not Found")
```

Here iam repeatedly calling `verifyHomePage` method 7 times using different `param` values.

How is it possbile to pass the 3 `params` as `array` values instead of `string` values.what i meant is
eg:

```
 verifyHomepage(idArray[],successMsg[],errorMsg[])
```

Comment: you don't specify the argument types in a function declaration, and if you want to pass a one-element array, that would be `[sth]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you suggest:

```
verifyHomepage(idArray[],successMsg[],errorMsg[])
```

is possible, but then you're maintaining three arrays that need to be kept in sync.  An Array of Hashes is a much cleaner approach:

```
def verifyHomepage(items)
  items.each do |item|
    begin
      page.find(item[:selector])
      puts item[:successMsg]
    rescue
      puts item[:errorMsg]
    end
  end
end

items = [{ :selector => "#logoAnchor",
           :successMsg => "logo anchor found",
           :errorMsg => "Logo anchor not Found"},
         { :selector => ".navbar-inner",
           :successMsg => "Header Bar found",
           :errorMsg => "Header Bar  not Found"},
         { :selector => ".unstyled",
           :successMsg => "All Occasions Frame found",
           :errorMsg => "All Occasions Frame not Found"},
         { :selector => "##easyPrintPromoBox",
           :successMsg => "Easy Print Frame",
           :errorMsg => "Easy Print Frame not Found"},
         { :selector => ".tabbable",
           :successMsg => "l3 Tabs  Featured Occasions/Pairings/ArtistEasy Print Frame",
           :errorMsg => "3 Tabs  Featured Occasions/Pairings/ArtistEasy Print Frame Not found"},
         { :selector => "##givingCardPromoBox",
           :successMsg => "Create the perfect gift found",
           :errorMsg => "Create the perfect gift not Found"},
         { :selector => ".footerr",
           :successMsg => "Footer Frame found",
           :errorMsg => "Footer Frame found not Found"}]

puts "Verifying Home Page"
verifyHomepage(items)
```

Comment: and now for the bonus question, what is the most elegant way to accept a single item as well as an array of items without obliging the caller to wrap their item in `[]`.

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of the splat operator to pass in a variable number of arguments to your method, and each argument can be a 3-element array.

```
def verifyHomepage(*args)
  args.each do |a|
    id = a[0]
    successMsg = a[1]
    errorMsg = a[2]
    # process args
  end
end

verifyHomepage(['.footerr', 'Footer Frame found', 'Footer Frame not found'], ['#giving', 'Create the perfect gift', 'not found'])
```